# Two independent drop down boxes. One onclick the other on hover

Tags: jquery

This may seem like a simple and straightforward question and it probably has a straightforward answer. I have two drop down boxes in my toolbar, one that drops on hover and the other on click and the other on hover.

I can't for the life of me figure out how to make them run independently. I am very new to jquery and have scoured the internet before coming here.

Fiddle without css but still does same thing.

http://jsfiddle.net/GQtuH/

Here is the jquery

```
$(document).ready(function () { 

$('#discoverDrop').hover(
    function () {
        //show its submenu
        $('ul, this').slideDown(500);

    }, 
    function () {
        //hide its submenu
        $('ul, thid').slideUp(500);         

});



$('#profile').toggle(function(){
        $('ul, this').slideDown(500);
    }, function(){
        $('ul, this').slideUp(500);
    });


});
```

And the neccesary markup

```
<span id="discoverDrop">
       <span id="drop"><m2>Discover</m2>
        <ul>
         <li><m2><a href="../artists"><m2>Artists</m2></a></li></m2>
         <li><m2><a href="../tracks"><m2>Tracks</m2></a></li></m2>
         <li><m2><a href="../sessions"><m2>Sessions</m2></a></li></m2>
         <li><m2><a href="../gigs"><m2>Gigs</m2></a></li></m2>
        </ul>         
       </span>
      </span>

      <span id="profile">
        <span id="profileDrop">
          <ul>
           <li><m2><a href="../phpscripts/logout.php"><m2>Logout</m2></a></li></m2>
           <li><m2><a href="../tracks"><m2>Tracks</m2></a></li></m2>
           <li><m2><a href="../sessions"><m2>Sessions</m2></a></li></m2>
           <li><m2><a href="../gigs"><m2>Gigs</m2></a></li></m2>
        </ul>         
        </span>
      </span>
```

Comment: I am not familiar with the `'ul, this'` syntax. What does it mean?

Comment: ya, I usually would do something like $(this).find(' > ul')

Comment: U might need $('ul', this) instead.   
Also there is one "thid" also out there

Comment: The ul is referencing the <ul> in the markup and the this is referencing the already called #discoverDrop. The ul, this seems to be the fault. Do you have any other suggestions?

Comment: 'ul',this is what i had before but that does not help me. Both do the same thing.

Comment: try ">ul" if you want to select just immediate child, "ul" will slect all the ul inside this.

Comment: Oh @sabithpocker thanks for pointing out the thid but still no change

Comment: If that too doesnt help, create a fiddle for some quick responses :)

Comment: @sabithpocker no luck, that just broke the whole thing

Comment: Fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/GQtuH/

Comment: Can you add the expected behaviour w.r.t the fiddle, to the question.

Comment: @JacobWindsor - http://jsfiddle.net/GQtuH/2/ ? It looks real weird since the layout is, well, not complete I assume. But the boxes are independent

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$(arg1, arg2)` `arg1` is usually a string containing selectors we need to get selected. `arg2` is a `jQuery Object` inside which we should check for it.

Doing `$('ul, this')` will pass a single argument `'ul, this'` and jQuery will search for elements with tagname `'ul'` and `'this'` throughout the document.

Doing $`('ul', this)` looks like what you want.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#discoverDrop').hover(
        function () {
            //show its submenu
            $('ul', this).slideDown(500);

        },
        function () {
            //hide its submenu
            $('ul', this).slideUp(500);         

    });
    $('#profile').toggle(function(){
            $('ul', this).slideDown(500);
        }, function(){
            $('ul', this).slideUp(500);
        });

});
```

---

```
<span id="discoverDrop">
   <span id="drop"><m2>Discover</m2>
        <ul>
         <li><m2><a href="../artists"><m2>Artists</m2></a></li></m2>
         <li><m2><a href="../tracks"><m2>Tracks</m2></a></li></m2>
         <li><m2><a href="../sessions"><m2>Sessions</m2></a></li></m2>
         <li><m2><a href="../gigs"><m2>Gigs</m2></a></li></m2>
        </ul>         
   </span>
</span>

<span id="profile">
    Click Me to Toggle
    <span id="profileDrop">
        <ul>
           <li><m2><a href="../phpscripts/logout.php"><m2>Logout</m2></a></li></m2>
           <li><m2><a href="../tracks"><m2>Tracks</m2></a></li></m2>
           <li><m2><a href="../sessions"><m2>Sessions</m2></a></li></m2>
           <li><m2><a href="../gigs"><m2>Gigs</m2></a></li></m2>
        </ul>         
    </span>
</span>
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/GQtuH/3/

**UPDATE**

If you are using `float right` for profile in the layout, its always recommended to put the right floated element first in the HTML. like :

```
<span id="profile">
...
</span>
<span id="discoverDrop">
...
</span>
```